# not insert duplicate values to database from user form

Tags: php, forms, jsp

I need to insert name from user form into SQL Database. for this i have two program sql.php is able to insert name into database. form.jsp gives user form to enter name.
connected MSSQL database using odbc

```
  $connect = odbc_connect('Sedbase','susername', 'pwd');
```

this query written in sql.php is able to insert values into database

```
   $query=("INSERT INTO namedb(name) VALUES ('$_POST[name]')");
   $result = odbc_exec($connect, $query);}
```

form.jsp has folowing codes

```
 <html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function validateform()
  {var y=document.forms["Form"]["comp"].value;
if (y==null || y=="")
    {
alert("");
  return false;
}
 }
  </script>
   </head>
```

when i insert name it should accept and store into database. that is happening . but when i insert same name also it is accepting.i do not want to insert same name again. It shouldn't accept same name and it should give message to the user that name already exist in DB, through some alert or text messages.

Comment: Just write a SELECT query for finding duplication before INSERT query

Comment: make the field unique, perform an ajax which queries the database for the same value and issue a warning that the name already exists, you can easily do this using jquery $.POST

Comment: can u please put it in a code format?

Answer (score 0):

You should use **UNIQ** or equivalent in you SQL schema where it's needed.

Then, in case of a particular return code, said **DUPLICATE KEY**, you can inform the user in javascript, with `alert()` or simply use a **SELECT** statement before **INSERT**-ing

Comment: i can't change schema, how select helps in this . am not understanding?

Comment: It helps to detect if the tuple exists already or not : `$query = ("SELECT "OK" FROM namedb(name) WHERE 'name' == '$_POST[name]')");`
If it returns "OK" when executing it, the name is already there.

Comment: its giving error on OK. and this qury not detects duplicate values again same name is getting inserted.

Comment: It's not the real SQL statement, you should adapting it a bit to fit your needs ;)
And "giving error" is a bit short to reply efficiency

Comment: is there any other way? can i compare textbox values with tuples in form.jsp?if so, how?

Comment: And i couldn't apply unique constraint to datatype varchar(max). how can i set unique constraint for this kind of datatypes?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways

1. Add a unique constraint on the column
2. Check whether the name already exists before inserting

Either ways your script is prone to sql injections. Please sanitize your user input : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Enforcement_at_the_coding_level